# Exclusion of region in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array (`dat`) of shape `(n,3)` where `n` denotes the number of rows, and the three columns represent the  `x` (column 0), `y` (column 1) and `z` (column 2) coordinates respectively.

I want to **EXCLUDE** those rows in this numpy array where the values of `x` lie between a certain limit ( `xlow < x < xupp` **AND** where the values of `y` lie between `ylow < x < yupp` **AND** where the values of `z` lie between `zlow < x < zupp`. I already have values of `[xlow, xupp, ylow, yupp, zlow, zupp]`.

I know how to find the region (rows) where the condition of exclusion holds using:

```
mark = np.where( ( dat[:,0]>xlow & \
                   dat[:,0]<xupp )  & \
                 ( dat[:,1]>ylow & \
                   dat[:,1]<yupp ) & \
                 ( dat[:,2]>zlow & \
                   dat[:,2]<zupp ) )
```

But, I want these rows to be excluded in my new array. How can I do this in numpy? Thanks.

Comment: Drop the `where` and use the not operator `~`.

Comment: Do you mean np.~(....)? I get error (invalid syntax) when I do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking the negation of the condition inside np.where(). Like this:

```
mark = np.where( ~( (dat[:,0]>xlow) & \
                    (dat[:,0]<xupp) & \
                    (dat[:,1]>ylow) & \
                    (dat[:,1]<yupp) & \
                    (dat[:,2]>zlow) & \
                    (dat[:,2]<zupp) ) )
```

Comment: You don't need the `where` when all you want to do is `dat[mark]`